# Listboxes with SelectionMode="Multiple" is not working in windows phone WebBrowser control

Tags: windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I'm developing a windows phone 8 app and I have added a WebBrowser control. If the control is displaying any page that contains multiple selection listbox, I've noticed that the user is only allowed to select only one item?! any fix/workaround?